# what is the delimiter in my text

Tags: python, split

I have a long messy file and my friend tells me that he has tab delimited that file..
But when i do :

```
  tokens = line.split("\t")
```

It doesnt splits...

But I dont know maybe I am missing something.. and my friend seems pretty sure that he the file is tab-delimited. and it looks like its tab-delimited as well

sample file

```
10      AccessibleComputing     0       381202555       2010-08-26T22:38:36Z    OlEnglish       7181920 #F3#    [[Help:Reverting|Reverted]] edits by [[Special:Contributions/76.28.186.133|76.28.186.133]] ([[User talk:76.28.186.133|talk]]) to last version by Gurch  #REDIRECT#F0#[[Computer#F0#accessibility]]#F0#{{R#F0#from#F0#CamelCase}}        lo15ponaybcg2sf49sstw9gdjmdetnk ,Computer_accessibility
```

Is there a way to know that hidden delimiter in python?

Maybe code the string in another format....?

Comment: I suspect these may be spaces

Comment: The sample you posted is space delimited, not tab delimited. You can tell by copying into notepad, trying to highlight the 'spaces' and seeing if they get highlighted in single characters or big blocky chunks.

Comment: using notepad++ you can display unvisible chars in text file

Comment: `print(repr(line))` will show you where the `'\t'` characters are.

Comment: Looks like it might be fixed field lengths to me. Hard to tell from one line :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just split on whitespace:

```
line.split()
```

[`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) with no arguments will split on variable-width whitespace, and remove leading and trailing whitespace as needed. Whitespace is any tab, space, newline or carriage return:

```
>>> '10      AccessibleComputing     0       381202555       2010-08-26T22:38:36Z    OlEnglish       7181920 #F3#    [[Help:Reverting|Reverted]] edits by [[Special:Contributions/76.28.186.133|76.28.186.133]] ([[User talk:76.28.186.133|talk]]) to last version by Gurch  #REDIRECT#F0#[[Computer#F0#accessibility]]#F0#{{R#F0#from#F0#CamelCase}}        lo15ponaybcg2sf49sstw9gdjmdetnk ,Computer_accessibility'.split()
['10', 'AccessibleComputing', '0', '381202555', '2010-08-26T22:38:36Z', 'OlEnglish', '7181920', '#F3#', '[[Help:Reverting|Reverted]]', 'edits', 'by', '[[Special:Contributions/76.28.186.133|76.28.186.133]]', '([[User', 'talk:76.28.186.133|talk]])', 'to', 'last', 'version', 'by', 'Gurch', '#REDIRECT#F0#[[Computer#F0#accessibility]]#F0#{{R#F0#from#F0#CamelCase}}', 'lo15ponaybcg2sf49sstw9gdjmdetnk', ',Computer_accessibility']
```

Comment: Splitting the edit message looks like the wrong behavior here, although the format given is simply awful.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have got the tabs and spaces muddled or converted? Maybe splitting on both tabs and spaces would help

```
import re
re.split('\t|    ', line)
```